# SaveChanges() method not saving changes to the database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I just started with Entity framework and I was able to do select operations using linq,but I had an issue with Inserting. I tried this sample to see whats wrong :

```
        testEntities te = new testEntities();
        te.Customer.Add(new Table {Id=1,Credit=200m,Name="test" });
        te.SaveChanges();
```

Well it appears that the changes the row was only added to the testEntites but not to the database and when I restart the application I find no rows added.
Thanks,

Comment: Do you get any error? Are you using any transaction scope?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Try creating `var t = new Table {Id=1,Credit=200m,Name="test" }; t.markAsAdded(); te.Customer.ApplyChanges(t); te.SaveChanges;`

Comment: What type is `te.Customer`?

Comment: Also, what kind of database? If local sql server (express) database, check if you've set it to "copy to output: always".

Comment: no errors at all @LasseV.Karlsen I created a service based db directly from visual studio

Comment: Is it code first approach? Is there any Fluent API mapping available for the entities?

Comment: te.Customer is a table

Comment: @SelvaTS sorry I didn't understand the question very well.

Comment: But I understood something the database that is being modified is the one in the debug folder and changes are not committed to the original database. Can that be fixed , thanks

Comment: Are you using a local database file?  Are you certain it's not getting [overwritten when you build the solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx)?

Comment: @Const how you created DB? System automatically created after the first run or you have created?

Comment: @DStanley exactly its being overwritten

Comment: @SelvaTS I simply Added new item to the project 'Service based DataBase'

Comment: @Const Read the link in my comment to see if you can configure the project appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

One way I fixed it was by making sure I was putting all the required fields on database. I was getting the same error before. I checked my database and I was not putting the not-nullable field when I was making the query. That solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while deleting records. Not sure what causes this, but I fixed it by forcibly changing the state of the entity. Some pseudo code:

```
Customer CustomerRecord = db.Customer.Find(Id);
te.Entry(CustomerRecord).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
te.SaveChanges();
```